# How to get third previous month from inputted month-year?

Tags: php, date, datetime

I am trying to get third previous month from inputted month-year ie. if I give `06-2016` as an input, it should give me `03-2016` as result. I have tried `strtotime("-3 Months")`. But it gives me just 3 months from current date time.

Can someone tell me how to solve it please.

**I have tried:**

```
$month = 06;
$year = 2016;

$d = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year);
$td = date("Y-m-d", $d);
$oldDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-3 Months"));
```

It gives me 3 months from current date. Any guesses how do I get the expected result ?

Comment: You just missed one part. The storetotime should be like this  `strtotime($td." -3 Months")`. You should mark the correct answer from bellow though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below. You need to use `date("F Y", strtotime( INPUT_DATE ." -3 months"))`

```
$month = 06;
$year = 2016;

$d = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year);
$td = date("Y-m-d", $d);
echo $olddate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime( $td ." -3 months"));
echo $months = date("F Y", strtotime( $td ." -3 months"));
```

**Output:**

```
2016-03-01
March 2016
```

**Online Demo: [Click Here](https://eval.in/560269)**

Answer (score 1):

strtotime of (Input Date ."-3 Months")

```
$month = 06;
$year  = 2016;

$d       = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year);
$td      = date("Y-m-d", $d);
$oldDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($td."-3 Months"));

$oldDate_MonthYear = date('m-Y', strtotime($td."-3 Months"));

echo $oldDate;
echo '<br />';
echo $oldDate_MonthYear;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Object Based.

```
$date1 = new DateTime("2016-06-01");
echo $startDate = $date1->modify("-3 month")->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and you should get desired result.

```
$prev_month_ts = strtotime('2016-06 -3 month');

$prev_month = date('Y-m', $prev_month_ts);

echo $prev_month;
```